# Assign SQL Server users to employees IDs

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database in SQL Server 2005.
Each database user exists in the **Employees** table with unique ID. So how can I assign a database user to an employee ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... I'm assuming you're using Windows logins and that the users are listed by their network IDs. So, then the question answers itself. It's already done. You might need to maintain a mapping table of login IDs to employee IDs, or you might be able to define a simple transformation (such as stripping off the domain name.) But, there's some chance the query you want is
SELECT "Lower level" from Subordination WHERE "Higher level" = CURRENT_USER;

Comment: Sure, Vlad. I'm happy to help. I log in every few months. How has it been going?